# How to solve your connection is not private while running running bookmark site on chrome?

Tags: amazon-web-services, testing, automated-tests, testcase

While running site on chrome. I am facing

"Your connection is not private"

How can I bypass this in headless Chrome?

I have tried to different method but it's not working.Please provide some references

Comment: Could you please edit you post to include your code that describes how you are currently running your tests with headless Chrome?

Comment: Hi @Govind welcome on board.
Your connection is not private means that your site, or the site you are trying to save the bookmark for is using HTTP instead of HTTPS, if it is your site just apply SSL certificate for it and chrome would consider browsing this site to be safe then.